# Distribution of reads across replicaSet in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I run several experiments in MongoDB (read queries) and I connect to my Replica Set with:

```
connection = MongoClient("publicIP1:27017,publicIP2:27017,publicIP3:27017,publicIP4:27017,publicIP5:27017",
replicaSet="rs0", readPreference='nearest',
localThresholdMS=500)
```

I have set readPreference='nearest' in order to read from any available member.

Here http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/high_availability.html says:

> "If multiple members match the read preference, PyMongo reads from
>   among the nearest members, chosen according to ping time. By default,
>   only members whose ping times are within x milliseconds of the nearest
>   are used for queries."

I set localThresholdMS=500 for load balancing.

So my question is, the read requests are distributed among the members of the replica set? (all the nodes have the same data)

If this is the case, how the returned data are composed together?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/#nearest explains it in a bit more details. Driver chooses a member based on ping, opens a cursor, and read all data from this node. It is on per-query base, not per document.

Comment: The link that I provide above says: "PyMongo distributes reads among matching members". You say that a member is chooses based on its ping and all the data are read from this node. I cannot understand it.

Comment: When you use `pymongo.MongoClient` to fetch documents like `db.test.find()` it chose which member to get data from. On multiple `find()` it may choose different members for each individual query. It is the "distribution of reads".  Once the member is chosen, the driver sends the query to it, retrieve the cursor, and iterate it to read all matching documents from this particular instance.